# plugin_action_links_{$plugin_file} hook not in the main plugin file

Tags: plugins, filters, hooks

I'm developing a plugin and I've organized its code in separate files. The admin functions file is inside an `/admin` subfolder. In this file I enqueue scripts and styles, add meta boxes and so on.

I'd like to add some action links to the installed plugins screen using the `plugin_action_links_{$plugin_file}` hook, but I cannot get it to work.

As this hook is added outside the main plugin file this doesn't work:

```
add_filter( 'plugin_action_links_' . plugin_basename( __FILE__ ),  array( $this, 'add_action_links' ) );
```

My question is, how can I get the `plugin_basename()` of the main plugin file from a different file in a subfolder? Is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply store the basename in a variable in the main file and reference that variable in the admin file.

If you are using classes, which I determine from your example code, you can simply create a static property in you main class and reference that in the admin class:

```
class My_Plugin {
    static $basename = null;

    public function __construct {
        $this->basename = plugin_basename(__FILE__);
    }
}

class My_Plugin_Admin {
    public function change_action_links() {
        add_filter( 'plugin_action_links_' . My_Plugin::$basename,  array( $this, 'add_action_links' ) );
    }
}
```